# Does any cross section of the Sierpinski carpet yield the Cantor set?

Tags: general-topology, fractals, cantor-set

My gut tells me that if you took a vertical cross section of the [Sierpinski carpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_carpet) at an $x$-coordinate *in the Cantor set*, the cross section would again be the Cantor set. However, I'm at a loss for how to prove this (or even give a heuristic argument).

Comment: On second thought, that cross section might actually just be the whole unit interval...

Comment: If $x$ is a rational point with denominator $3^n$, then the cross section includes a line segment.